# iPhone: How to create dynamic instances for any built-in class object?

Tags: iphone

I want to create dynamic instances for a built in class object. I am not sure how to achieve this.
For example, the below audio player object instance i want to create dynamically, so that I can play dynamic multiple data.

```
audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:pData error:nil];
```

instead of this, i want to be something like below,

```
audioPlayer1 = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:pData error:nil];
audioPlayer2 = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:pData error:nil];
audioPlayer3 = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:pData error:nil];
```

Here, 1, 2, 3 can be added dynamically, because i don't know how many i have to add at once, it has to be dynamically created.

I though i can do like,

```
AVAudioPlayer *[NSString stringWithFormat:@"audioPlayer%d", value] = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:pData error:nil];
```

But this is not acceptable.

Could someone help me on this to resolve?

Answer (score 4):

Just use a loop to create the instances and put them into a mutable array.

```
NSMutableArray *players = [NSMutableArray array];
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:pData error:nil];
    [players addObject:audioPlayer];
}
```

Comment: Use `objectAtIndex:`. And read the documentation (or an introductory book) to learn these basics.

Comment: If you use an NSMutableDictionary instead you can refer to each member by a key value.

Comment: This is not useful. I need to play a set of small audio at one time, then immediately within 2 seconds, i need to play set of another audio, if i use this code, then before completely playing the first of set audio the second set of audio has started, so the first set of audio not played all.

Comment: Then why didn't you state any of these requirements in your question? Do you expect us to read your mind?

Answer (score 0):

As `@Ole Begemann` suggested, put the dynamic creations in a for loop. But, What I would do is create a method accepting a `dynamic` value of how many need to be created:

```
-(void)createAudioPlayers:(int)count {

    //Assuming `players` array is declared in your header as an NSMutableArray and initialized.

    pData = ... // your data

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

     AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:pData error:nil];
     [audioPlayer play];
     [players addObject:audioPlayer];

    }

}
```

Now you can simply pass an `int` value, on how many players you want to create.

```
[self createAudioPlayers:4];
```

or

```
[self createAudioPlayers:8];
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: You probably might not want each audio player to play automatically upon creation, as in this code ;-)